# Shortcut to hide all the opened tabs/windows in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any shortcut key to hide all the opened tabs/windows (server explorer, Team explorer, Solution explorer etc..)in visual studio? I don't want to make it full screen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but as of MSVC 2017 (version 15.5.4) there's no such shortcut.

Here's a nifty page that lists all the keyboard shortcuts: http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2017/

Comment: Thanks! It is strange that there is no key combination for this. Can we bind keys manually for this?

Comment: My understanding is that you can only bind keys to an existing command (not talking about MSVC extensions here) and since one doesn't exist there would be nothing to bind a key shortcut to

Comment: Hey YePhIck.. I am able to bind a shortcut key for this.. if you go to **Winodws -> Auto Hide All** option there where we can able to hide all the open windows. We can bind it in **options->Environment ->keyboard-> Select Windows.AutoHideAll** and map any key combination you want. But looks like no keys to get the hidden windows back.

Comment: @Dilip Windows Auto Hide All doesn't close the Tabs however.

Comment: @WaltRitscher I have tried it in VS2017, VS2015 and VS2013. It is working for me. Can you please reset your VS setting and try again.

Comment: @Dilip What settings did you configure for VS.  I use General Developer.

Comment: @WaltRitscher I generally choose "Web Development" option

Answer (score -1):

enter WINDOWS KEY+M, all tabs will be minimized.
for previous window to open enter WINDOWS KEY+LEFT SHIFT+M.